# How to run FORTRAN program on all the files in a folder?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

As of now, I'm opening one file with a .txt extension and running a fortran code on it. However, if I want the program to run on on all the files in a folder with all kinds of extensions. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you are stuck with FORTRAN77, one possible solution is to read the input file name from standard input and open that file accordingly:

```
character(len=9999) inputFile

read(unit=5,fmt=*)inputFile
open(unit=21,file=trim(inputFile))
```

Then, execute your program on all files through a shell script loop:

```
for file in *;do
    echo $file | myFortranProgram
done
```

If you have a more modern compiler, you can use a Fortran 2003 feature `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT`:

```
character(len=9999) :: inputFile 

call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,VALUE=inputFile)
open(unit=21,file=trim(inputFile))
```

Then execute your program through a loop as described above:

```
for file in *;do
    ./myFortranProgram $file
done
```

Remember that when looping over files, you are responsible for making sure that your Fortran program will work with those files and that it is able to handle exceptions, e.g. directories or some other file extensions, or loop over specific files from shell accordingly.

Comment: most "old" f77 compilers support this functionality via iargc / getarg functions.

Comment: @george Sure, but these are not part of the standard, and would not advise using if one cares about portability.

Answer (score 2):

I usually create a file with a list of the files that I want to process, e.g., using the *ls* or *find* commands on a Unix OS. This also allows one to modify the list with an editor. Then I design the Fortran program to read the filenames from that file, then open, process and close those files in succession.

If you can predict possible filenames based on a pattern, you can test whether a file of a particular name exists using the INQUIRE statement.   This could be used to loop through all possible filenames.  This may or may not be practical depending on how many possible files there are.

Comment: I've done the ls command in DOS and obtained the list of all the files in the current folder so that their names can be read by the program and all those files can be processed. But, I've got a problem running the program successfully on all the files:                     CHARACTER :: FILE_NAME, FILE_NAME2

OPEN(UNIT=10, FILE='print.txt')

DO 
READ(10,'(A)', END=700) FILE_NAME

FILE_NAME2 = ('MODIFIED' // FILE_NAME // '.txt')

   
!!OPENS EXISTING FILE TO BE READ AND THEN PROGRAM WRITES IT TO 2ND MODIFIED FILE!!
  
OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE=FILE_NAME)
OPEN(UNIT=2, FILE=FILE_NAME2)

Comment: You really should delete this comment since you've now asked another question.  No-one's going to spend much time trying to read a program in a comment.

Comment: Instead I think it would be beter for you to add this to the above question.    You say you "got a problem."   What is the problem?

Comment: I'm expecting an output with multiple files written to the folder after being processed named 'MODIFIED...txt'. However, as of now, I'm the only outputs I'm getting are 2 files of 0KB names '3' and 'M'. No idea where to start. The program successfully compiles and is able to execute though.

Comment: The 'test.txt' file contains names of all the files in the current folder to be input into the read function of the fortran program. Currently, to test it out, I have 2 files in there and I AM getting 2 files as outputs except that they're empty and names wierdly

Comment: Re the weird names: did you use "trim" in creating the output names?  Otherwise the output names might contain spaces or get truncated.